# How to write Mongo query to find video details between two dates

Tags: mongodb

In My mongodb there is a video collection in which  there is a creationTime list like following and i want to fetch the record between any two dates by using creationTime.

"creationTime" : {
         "logtime" : ISODate("2013-08-12T10:54:44.914Z"),
         "logtimeStr" : "12-08-2013 04:24:44",
         "day" : 12,
         "month" : 8,
         "year" : 2013,
         "hour" : 16,
         "min" : 24,
         "second" : 44
 }

Answer (score 1):

A little bit nicer way to write a range query, and also just mentioning that **`$and`** is implicit within MongoDB and only needs to be used in specific cases that actually require it:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "creationTime.logtime": { 
        "$gt": new Date("2014-08-01"), "$lt" new Date("2014-08-13") 
    }
})
```

At least that is the theory for a range query. But currently you have a **really big problem** and that is your dates are actually being stored as **strings**.

This is a huge problem as basically when these are strings ( and especially as they are currently formatted ) then you are stuck with a lexical comparison of strings, and the strings you have to not lexically compare properly in the sense of one being "greater" in value than the other.

Strings would need to be presented in the order of "year" then "month" then "day", and with **two** digit representations in order to match a lexical comparison. What you have currently does not.

But do not change the strings, change them to proper date types and then the query as shown will actually work correctly.

Comment: @user3656078 Please tell you what?

Comment: Thanks for advice but this type of query i write on mongo shell but i am not able to convert those query in Criteria.where.... can you please help me.Query is...db.collection.count( { $and: [ { "creationTime.day": { "$gte":1,"$lte":23 } }, { "creationTime.month": { "$gte":5,"$lte":5 } },{ "creationTime.year": { "$gte":2014,"$lte":2014 } } ] } )

Comment: Thanks I solved this problem by using  BasicQuery class

Answer (score 0):

Use Mongodb comparison operators [$lt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) and [$gt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/)   ( or $lte & $gte for inclusive limits )

How you create START_DATE and END_DATE depends on language you are using .e.g. for javascript you would use `new Date()`

```
db.myVideoCollection.find({
 '$and':[
          {'$creationTime.logtime':{'$gt':START_DATE },
          {'$creationTime.logtime':{'$lt':END_DATE }
        ]
 })
```